# Host name issue with WSFederated Authentication

Tags: federated-identity

I have configured Local STS with my web application (which is hosted in IIS 7 and has the host name as `www.abc.com`) and it can receive the claims from the STS and it can login. Now I have added another host name (`www.xyz.com`) to my web application. If user a login to a page in the application using `www.abc.com/page1` and it redirects to local STS and it authenticates the user and adds the security token. Now if the user visits `www.xyz.com/page2` it also redirects to the STS for authentication.

If a user either logged in `www.abc.com` or `www.xyz.com` they need to access the other domain page with out login. Is it possible? How do we achieve this?

Comment: Please add some details about what technology you are using. Ideally with some sample code you tried.

Comment: I am using asp.net 4.5 website and hosted in IIS 7. I am using WSFederatedAuthenticationModule which redirects to an Identity provider for authentication and i can receive the claims. It is working fine when i have only one host name for the website. When i add another host name it redirects to identity provider login page.  if the user is already logged in using domain A and if they visit the page in domain B they should not enter their login again. Is it possible to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In broad strokes, if you have two different relying parties, each needs to route the user to the IDP.  If the IDP is configured for single sign on, the user will only notice the routing to the IDP the first time. On the second routing, (assuming same browser session and that the routing is within the lifetime supported by the IDP) the user will be authenticated without seeing a page at the IDP and being required to present credentials.

So, part of your answer hinges around what you mean by login: if you mean "experience a challenge and enter credentials" by log in, you should be able to enable this by simply ensuring that the IDP is configured for single sign on.

On the other hand, if by login you mean the redirect to the IDP, then you need to make sure the application is able to share state across the different page names. Note that usual management of state is via cookies, and note that a cookie for abc.com will not be returned to a web page named xyz.com. There are a number of clever ways to resolve this, although i am not aware of any simple application configuration solutions. One example is to have some part of both the abc.com page and the xyz.com page accessed by the url shared.com. State cookies can then be set by the shared.com transaction when logging into abc.com and read by the shared.com transaction when subsequently accessing xyz.com.

I've never had to implement such a cross domain cookie solution and have only had off-hand conversations with colleagues about it: we've always found the silent redirect of single sign on to meet our requirements. Careful research into the privacy impact of such a solution and the likelihood that such cookies might be blocked should be considered before development.

Comment: Assuem that the IDP is configured with SSO. Now IDP writes auth cookie in RP1(on successful login) and upon redirection to a page in RP2, WSFederatedAuthenticationModule checks for auth cookie it doesn't find(RP1 and RP2 are in different domains so RP1 can not pass the auth cookie to RP2), so it redirects to IDP. Now my question is whether the IDP is intelligent enough to identify that the same user or the browser has already authenticated for RP1, so i wont redirect to login page, i simply return the auhorized token to RP2 or do we need to pass any information from RP2 to IDP?

Comment: The IDP has its own cookie. The IDP passes the authentication state to the RP1 in the SAML POST to RP1's ACS. RP1 then sets its own cookie. The point of SSO is that when the the user is sent to the IDP from RP2, the IDP checks the user's session state (as keyed from the IDP's cookie). If the session state is still valid, the user is returned to RP2 as authorized, without experiencing a challenge.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I need one more clarification. You said that "the user is sent to the IDP from RP2, the IDP checks the user's session state (as keyed from the IDP's cookie)". RP2 does not send any information about the user(when the redirection is happen from RP1, RP2 does not have any information about the logged in user). How does the IDP identifies the user and knew that the user is already logged in thru RP1?

Comment: The IDP does not know (necessarily) that the user has previously logged in through any **particular** relying party. The IDP maintains its session for the user with a cookie in the IDP domain (in most cases; any exceptions will still act in the same way from the RP point of view).

Comment: Hi, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. You can also take a look at [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have accepted your suggestion as the answer. Once again I appreciate your quick response.